# React Js, problemas al renderizar un JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

[image: Este es el error que me tira el codigo, no se porque no encuentra, cuando luego de borrar esa "url" que no encuentra, se carga el State y puedo mostrarlo perfectamente]

**Esta es mi peticion al BACK con un useEffect()**

```
const HomeHeroe = ({handle}) => {


const id = useParams();
const routerHistory = useHistory();
const resultSession = localStorage.getItem('token');
const [heroe,setHeroe] = useState([]);

const [isFetching,setIsFetching] = useState(false);

 useEffect(()=>{
     setIsFetching(true);
    const HereoById = async (id)=>{
        await api.post('/index', id).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.data);
            
           return  setHeroe({...res.data});
         
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
    HereoById(id);
    setIsFetching(false);
 },[]);
```

Aqui tenemos el return, que luego de actualizar la pagina, me devuelve los datos sin nigun tipo de problema, hasta que llega un punto que si cargo algun dato mal o si pongo **heroe.image.url** me devuelve ese error de que no esta definida la propiedad.
**

```
return (<>
    {!resultSession ? (alert("Sin autorizacion para el sitio, Ingrese"), routerHistory.push('/login')) :
        <>
        <div>
            <div className="m-0 row  justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-auto">
                    <button onClick={footerOut} className='btn btn-block bg-success mb-2 mt-2 ml-2'>Quitar Footer</button>
                </div>
                <div className="col-auto">
                    <button onClick={footerOn} className='btn btn-block  bg-success mb-2 mt-2'>Ver Footer</button>
                </div>
               
            </div>
            <div className="m-0 row  justify-content-center">
              
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <Container >
        <Row>
   
            <Col className='text-center mb-2'>
            <Card className='cardHero' border="danger">
            
         
                <Card.Body>
                <a><img src={heroe.image.url}/></a>
                {isFetching && <Loading />}
                 <Card.Title>{heroe?.name}</Card.Title>
                 <a> <img /> </a> 
                 <Card.Header>{Object.keys(heroe.connections)}</Card.Header>
                 <Card.Header>{Object.values(heroe.connections)} </Card.Header>
                 <Card.Text>
                 </Card.Text>
                {/* <Button onClick={()=>{routerHistory.push('/home')}}>Boton,VerQueHacer</Button> */}
                </Card.Body>
             </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>

        
         </Container>
         </>
   

}
</>);
```

}

`export default HomeHeroe`;

LUEGO AL BORRAR ESOS DATOS SUPUESTAMENTE ERRONEOS, ME DEVUELVE EL STATE CARGADO Y PUEDO MOSTRAR LOS DATOS COMO QUIERO. NO LOGRO SOLUCIONARLO, ALGUNA IDEA?? ***GRACIAS COMUNIDAD COMO SIEMPRE!!!***
[image: LA IMAGEN DEL JSON PUESTO EN PANTALLA CON LA DEVOLUCION DEL STATE POR CONSOLA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás seteando mal el valor de tu `state`. Lo inicializas como un array vacío, pero en el **setHeroes** de tu `useEffect` conviertes la respuesta de tu *request* a un objeto.

```
setHeroe(res.data)
```

Esto debería funcionar. Y lo otro, es que no necesitas retornar el *state* ;)

Nos comentas cualquier cosa.

Comment: Gracias mi amigo. Claramente me sirvio, un error tan tonto me llevo tantos dolores de cabeza!!! gracias!!